# Meaning of "whip" in a song by The Fold

Tags: meaning, nouns, translation, lyrics

My kids watch the "Lego NinjaGo" series and have been asking me about the title song, called "Weekend Whip" by The Fold. As much as I tried looking for the meaning of the word "whip" in the context of the song I couldn't find anything that would make sense. I guess it should mean something like "fight" or "training", but I am not sure about either. Could someone shed some light on it for me? Here's a short extract for reference:

> We just jump up, kick back, whip around and spin,
>   and then we jump back, do it again
>   Ninja-Go!
>   Ninja, come on, come on
>   and do the weekend whip!

Comment: Consider taking a "whip" -- a leather belt of sorts -- and waving it around over your head or as you turn in a circle.  To "whip" is to move in a rapid semi-circular motion, generally with some sort of strap or lever arm extended from the axis of motion.

Comment: "Do the weekend whip" is simply providing a name for the dance.

Comment: So when they're singing "We're ready for the fight we know the drill" and "We slept on Thursday just to get it over // The whip's a day away!", they're singing about a nearing dance?

Comment: They're dancing like Ninjas.

Comment: Okay then, thanks! It’s still pretty weird, but okay. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the song, but when I read it in your question, I immediately thought of the meaning "to move quickly", which is borne out by these two definitions:

> verb:
>
> *[no object, with adverbial of direction]*
>   Move fast or suddenly in a specified direction.
>   *‘he whipped round to face them’*
>
> *[with object and adverbial of direction]*
>   Take out or move (something) fast or suddenly.
>   *‘he whipped out his revolver and shot him’*
>
> Source: [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/whip)

So "**whip around**" means to turn around very quickly - just as a person holding a whip would move it very quickly to 'whip' someone.

Comment: Well, yes, but “the weekend whip”?

Comment: As I said, I'm not familiar with the song - nor the series - but my guess is that it's something they often do at the weekend.

Comment: I understand, yeah. The question for me is — *what* do they often do at the weekend.

Comment: @AntonZujev At the weekend they do what they describe in the first two lines of the song!!

Comment: “It’s time for training and we’re getting started,//it’s on, you know.”? It seems more likely that they’re singing about the training that they do to prepare for the whip.

Comment: If you can interpret it yourself, they why ask me?  But the words quoted in your comment are not included in your Q. and I already *twice* told you that I'm not familiar with the song, so don't expect me to come up with information not included in your Q.!

Comment: Additionally, your comments above asking about the 'weekend' bit had already been answer yesterday by @Hot Licks in the previous comments immediately below the main Q.!

Comment: Hey, I’m just answering your comments — which I’m thankful for, really! Not blaming you for anything or trying to argue.